# Missing header row in query result

Tags: pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to connect and query a DB2 database.  The result returned does not include a header row.
my code:

```
import csv
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=PMDATABASE connect 32;PWD=xzxy')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

querySQL = "SELECT * FROM tabl100 WHERE dist_typ_cd='H' with ur for fetch only fetch first 5 rows only;"
data = cursor.execute(querySQL)

with open("data.csv", 'w') as FH:
while True:
    rows = cursor.fetchmany(5) 
    if not rows:
        break
    for  row in rows:
        FH.write(",".join(str(element) for element in row))
        FH.write("\n")
```

output

1,10,0,H,0,2015-10-28,None,......
1,11,0,H,0,2022-01-27,None,......

Answer (score 0):

Most database libraries intended primarily for use within a program (as opposed to an interactive query tool to be used by a human) only return the data, not the column names. We usually have to retrieve the column names separately. For example, with pyodbc

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT 1 AS foo, 2 AS bar")
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x000000969BA8B130>
>>> cursor.fetchall()
[(1, 2)]
>>> [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
['foo', 'bar']
```